# How can I monitor my ISP's connection quality over time?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, ping, isp

I've got a very bad ISP and want to monitor the connection quality over a month's time.

At the moment I just wrote a script which logs ping requests to Google's DNS server `8.8.8.8`.

How can I do that more efficiently? Is there a better way to achieve long term monitoring?

Or a command line tool to measure the bandwidth? Then i could run a cronjob to do this.

Comment: Do you want to monitor it constantly over a month? Or at certain periods of time? Depending on what your script actually does, I would suggest you have Task Scheduler (or similar) run the script every 3 hours every day and just let the log files build.

Comment: Doesn't matter, ive enough diskspace to handle this. But it would be cool to have a tool which summerize the results in a nice way.

Answer (score 22):

You can monitor connection quality over time with [SmokePing](https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/). In a single graph you get round-trip time, jitter and packet loss. Excellent to monitor links.

[image: Example of graph generated by SmokePing]

Comment: looks like you can use this tool for free from DSLreports and get results over 24 hours from 3 different locations

Answer (score 6):

Update Dec. 2020

As I run a simple Linux home server, I run InfluxDB, Telegraf and Grafana. Telegraf is easily configured to capture useful information and I have it capturing DNS performance of several DNS servers (so I know to change if my chosen one is under-performing) and I ping several endpoints so that I can check for poor latency. The data is sent from Telegraf to InfluxDB and charted in Grafana.

Another alternative for those who don't want to use an external or other service. I use InfluxDB and Grafana anyway for Home Automation with Node-RED and all those services with Mosquitto all runs happily on a Pi.

---

I would switch to using a tool to monitor things.

Assuming that you can ping your router, you could try something like the [thinkbroadband monitor tool](http://www.thinkbroadband.com/ping). This will give you excellent information on the quality of your connection.

[DSLreports](http://www.dslreports.com/tools) also has some useful tools.

If you run a server off your connection, you might also want to try a free subscription with one of the web site monitoring services such as http://monitis.com

For testing outward rather than inward, have a look at:
http://www.guidingtech.com/1836/5-power-tools-to-check-broadband-speed-and-quality/
Which lists some tools such as speedtest.net which is an excellent monitor that you run on a PC on your local network.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a cable modem, typically you can access a web page (192.168.100.1 has worked twice for me in the past) and you can look at the signal/noise ratio as reported by the modem.

DSL modems typically have this information as well.

Comment: This could be a good additional source for an own tool

Answer (score 1):

If you're located in France (*), one such attempt is [Grenouille](http://grenouille.com/index.php). It's free but it used to under-assess my bandwidth when I was using it a few years ago. Note that both the website and software are in French.

(*) http://grenouille.com/ma_grenouille/modify.php says:

> Ami(e)s belges, suisses ou québecois (et autres pays francophones) :
>   grenouille.com n'est disponible qu'en France pour le moment, un
>   déploiement vers d'autres pays est prévu mais ce n'est pas pour tout
>   de suite... :-)

In English: not available outside France.